# transfering a non serializable object in WCF C#

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

Suppose i have a class that does not have the serializable attribute defined for it. Is there a way to transfer a specific instance from an ASP.NET application to a C# rest client?

Comment: You can create a serialization proxy for that class.

Comment: Do you have a link for a tutorial?

Comment: Create a wrapper class around that object that you can serialize.